# Speeding up import of data into Neo4j graph database

Tags: xml, database, graph, neo4j, nodes

I'm working on a project in which we have to create graphs from reading an xml file with the nodes information, I already have this part, but the process creating the nodes and the relationships is too long, it takes 31 minutes in computer with Core 2 Duo, 6GB RAM, on Windows and 16 minutes on Fedora, in other computer Core i5 and 4GB RAM takes aprox. 3 minutes and in a Core i7 computer.

So, my question here is, what's wrong? What can I do to acelerate this process?

I modified the configuration file `neo4j.properties` and no effect at all, it continues taking too long, any idea about that?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some of your code, so we can see how you are adding the data? How manay nodes and relationships are you adding, and do they have any properties? More detail would help...

Comment: do you use batch insert or transactions?

Comment: please provide more data about the xml syntax and your import method. i personally used the gremlin graphML.import() and it took the same time on a linux server and windows laptop.

Comment: Pablo did you figure out the reason meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking us why it is so slow between the 2 machines, or just in general?

Perhaps you can provide us with information regarding the operations you are doing with this import?

I ask because I've worked with the batch inserter myself and there are certain operations which can take longer then others, such as the index lookups. My use case however allowed me to optimize my load by 1 order of magnitude by exploiting parallel programming.

Can you provide us with more information?